# Is is possible to use shorthand option_settings with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

When writing `.ebextensions` `.config` files, Amazon allows for long and shortform entries, for example these two configurations are identical:

Long form:

```
"option_settings": [
    {
        'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
        'OptionName': 'DBEngine',
        'Value': 'postgres'
    },
    {
        'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
        'OptionName': 'DBInstanceClass',
        'Value': 'db.t2.micro'
    }
]
```

Shortform:

```
"option_settings": {
  "aws:rds:dbinstance": {
    "DBEngine": "postgres",
    "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro"
   }
}
```

However, all of the configurations I've seen [only specify using a long form with boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html):

```
response = eb_client.create_environment(
... trimmed ...
    OptionSettings=[
        {
            'Namespace': 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName': 'DBEngineVersion',
            'Value': '5.6'
        },
... trimmed ...
)
```

Is it possible to use a dictionary with shortform entries with `boto3`?

<sub>**Bonus:** If not, why not?</sub>

Comment: It is simple, boto3 currently only parse the long form. For the shorthand, it is no possible until somebody push code that handle both shorthand and full format.

Answer (score 2):

Trial and error suggests **no, you can not use the shortform config type**.

However, if you are of that sort of persuasion you can do this:

```
def short_to_long(_in):
    out = []
    for namespace,key_vals in _in.items():
        for optname,value in key_vals.items():
            out.append(
                {
                    'Namespace': namespace,
                    'OptionName': optname,
                    'Value': value
                }
            )
    return out
```

Then elsewhere:

```
response = eb_client.create_environment(

    OptionSettings=short_to_long({
      "aws:rds:dbinstance": {
        "DBDeletionPolicy": "Delete", # or snapshot
        "DBEngine": "postgres",
        "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro"
        },
    })
```